# Determine if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{n}}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{n}}$. If I do ratio test, I get $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = e^{f(n)}$ where $f(n) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}})} \to \frac{0}{2} = 0$. Since $e^0 = 1$, the series diverges.

Is this the correct method? Seems fishy to me...

Comment: Look up the ratiotest again. If the limit is 1 you can't conclude anything.

Comment: $[e^{-\sqrt n}]^{1/n} = e^{-1/\sqrt n} \to e^0 =1,$ so the root test tells us nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Using some power series:

$$e^{\sqrt n}=1+\sqrt n+\frac{n}2+\frac{n\sqrt n}6+\frac{n^2}{24}=\ldots\ge\frac{n^2}{24}\implies e^{-\sqrt n}\le\frac{24}{n^2}$$

and the comparison test gives us at once convergence.

Answer (score 1):

You can also show $e^{-\sqrt n} < 1/n^2$ for large $n.$